# SVG: Left line of rect is not displayed in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I have a small problem with SVG and Firefox.

My example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="margin: auto; position: relative; width: 1264px;">
         <div style="width: 1264px; top: 1px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; height: 1300px;">
            <div style="left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px;">
               <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;">
                  <div>
                     <svg:svg style="position: absolute; left: 435px; top: 520px;" width="80" height="60">
                        <svg:g id="rect1103" x="435" y="520" width="80" height="60">
                           <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="80" height="60" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1;"/>
                        </svg:g>
                     </svg:svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox 19.0.2 the left line is not displayed.
With chrome it works great...

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You've mistyped the width of the `<rect>` element as wdith Seems to display OK as far as I can see once that is corrected.

If the typo is not your problem then this issue is that you're displaying a 1px wide line, but clipping away half of it (the rect is at 0,0 so 1/2 the stroke is within the rect and half the stroke is outside and the outside part of the stroke is clipped away).

Possible solutions.

- Move the rect to be at x="0.5" y="0.5" and decrease the width/height
  by 1 so that the whole stroke is visible.
- Increase the stroke width so more of the stroke that's inside the rect is visible.

And no, whether a stroke of 1/2 a pixel is displayed or not is not a bug.

Comment: I corrected the typo, it was just in stackoverflow, not in my browser. I still have the problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying helping me:) Actually 0,5pixel black should be display as grey. Why width and height are not working in the same way?

Comment: Maybe, you're relying on details of the antialiasing implementation for that to be true.